# Implicit 'this' when calling base class' constructor

Tags: c++, this

I hope the following snippet explains it all:

```
struct TBase {
  virtual void f() {}
};

struct TDerived : public TBase {
    TDerived() {
      /* These are all fine either under GCC 4.4.3, ICC 12 and Comeau online: */
      f();
      this->f();
      TBase::f();
      this->TBase::f();

      /* This one fails under Comeau: */
      TBase::TBase();

      /* While this one fails in every case: */
      //this->TBase::TBase();

      /* e.g. GCC says:
         test.cpp: In constructor ‘TDerived::TDerived()’:
         test.cpp:17: error: invalid use of ‘struct TBase’  */
    }
    void f() {}
};
```

The question is: why? (i.e. why is `TBase::TBase()` wrong, according to Comeau C++? Why is `this->TBase::TBase()` even wronger?)

Comment: `TBase` isn't a member of `*this`, which is why `this->TBase::TBase();` fails.

Comment: @daknøk The same argument applies to `this->TBase::f()`? Wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you cannot call any constructor directly (§12.1 (2) ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)). If you want to call a base class constructor, you will have to do so in the initializer list, i.e.:

```
TDerived() : TBase() {
}
```

The main reason for this is that by the time control reaches the first executable code line of your derived constructor, it is guaranteed that the base class object is already fully constructed (§12.6.2 (5) and (6) ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)). Since constructors are commonly used for resource acquisition (i.e. RAII), it would be an error if it was allowed to "double"-construct an object.

Comment: More generally, you cannot call *any* constructor directly (except in an initialiser list).

Comment: Yep. Added that and a reference to the standard.

Comment: OK, right. But since constructors do not have names, what is the purpose for specyfying their scope? I mean: why is it allowed to write `TBase::TBase()`?

Comment: Well for one thing, it should be just easier to implement when you don't have different scope rules for constructors, thats why TBase::TBase() is allowed in the first place, I assume. What happens, however, is not that the base class constructor gets called but rather this line creates a fresh, anonymous object of type TBase which is immediately discarded.

Comment: @user1225822: The name of a class is injected into the class's scope, so `TBase::TBase` is equivalent to `TBase` (or indeed to `TBase::TBase::TBase::TBase`). It refers to the class, not the constructor. `TBase::TBase()` creates a temporary object (just like `int()` also would).

Comment: Thanks guys. I know that `TBase::TBase()` takes no effect :), but what I tried to point out are the scope rules that I don't understand. Noteworthy, Comeau does not accept `TBase::TBase()` at all (!)

Comment: @Mike Not true. You can, using the placement-new syntax.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Indeed, you can call a constructor indirectly by creating an object, perhaps using some form of `new`. You can't call it directly, though.

Comment: @Mike No. That’s not what I meant. You can call the constructor directly on an existing object (in the C++ sense) via the placement-new syntax: `new (&obj) T();`. This looks like `new` but the syntax is misleading. In reality this just calls the constructor of `T` on the memory location pointed to by `&obj`. It’s the direct equivalent of saying `obj.T::T()` (which obviously doesn’t compile).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: OK, it's not worth quibbling over the semantics of what "directly" means. If you choose to regard constructing an object in a preallocated block of memory as a "direct constructor call", then feel free to read my comment as "you cannot call *any* constructor directly (except in an initialiser list, or via a placement-new expression)".